# Finding weekly combinations of items bought together using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a `df`:

```
date            category            subcategory         order_id        product_id       branch
2021-05-04      A                   aa                  10              5                web
2021-06-04      A                   dd                  10              2                web
2021-05-06      B                   aa                  18              3                shop
2021-07-06      A                   aa                  50              10               web
2021-07-06      C                   cc                  10              15               web
2021-07-05      A                   ff                  101             30               shop
2021-10-04      D                   aa                  100             15               shop
```

I am trying to answer a question *which items categories and subcategories are bought together* per branch type weekly. I am thinking of grouping the `order_ids` and aggregating the `category & subcategory` to a `list`  like so:

```
a = (df.set_index('date')
     .groupby(['order_id','branch'])
     .resample('W-MON', label = 'left')
     .agg({'category':list, 'subcategory':list}))
```

Which returns :

```
                                                category            subcategory
order_id        branch          date            [A, A, A]           [aa, dd, aa]
10              web             2021-05-04      ...                 ...
18              shop            ...
50              web
100             web
101             shop
```

I am trying to build a structure which would show the frequency of each variation of the `categories` and `subcategories` bought each week per `branch`, something similar to this:

```
branch                                  date                        
                                        2021-05-04                      2021-05-011
                                                                        ...
web                  category            3, [A, A, A] 
                                         2, [A, A] 
                                         2, [A, A, B, B]

                     subcategory         5, [aa, dd, aa]
                                         4, [dd, aa]
                                         1, [dd]

shop                 category            3, [A, A, A] 
                                         2, [A, A] 
                                         2, [A, A, B, B]

                     subcategory         5, [aa, dd, aa]
                                         4, [dd, aa]
                                         1, [dd]
```

Where the number before the list denotes the number of times a certain combinations of `categories` and `subcategories` were bought in the same order. I am unsure how to achieve such a structure or a similar one that would show the weekly combination frequencies by `branch`. The order of the `product_id` in the order does not matter as the final basket is the same.

So the goal is to see the frequency of `categories, subcategories & product_ids` bought in the same order weekly. So if 2 different orders have the same products, the aggregated result would show `2, [A,B]  [aa, bb]  [5, 2]` where the lists hold category, subcategory & product_id combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime as dt

# df=pd.read_excel('demo.xlsx')

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date']=df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year_week'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y_%U')

df['orderid_year_week']=df['order_id'].astype(str)+'_'+df['year_week']

df=df.sort_values(['category', 'subcategory','product_id'], ascending=[True, True,True])

a = (df.set_index('orderid_year_week')
     .groupby(['year_week','order_id'],sort=False)
     .agg({'category':list, 'subcategory':list,'product_id':list})).reset_index()

a['category'] =a['category'].astype(str)
a['subcategory'] =a['subcategory'].astype(str)
a['product_id'] =a['product_id'].astype(str)

df=pd.pivot_table(a,index=['year_week','category','subcategory','product_id'],values='product_id',aggfunc='count').reset_index()

df.rename({'order_id':'count'},axis=1,inplace=True)
```

The output looks like this (I have added a few more entries on top of the sample that you provided):

[image]

Some things in your explanations are not crystal clear. But let me know if this fully answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question.
Are you aware of the data mining technique named the "Apriori Algorithm".

What you are doing is mining association rules which is commonly used to establish an understanding of things that were bought together.

I strongly recommend using the frequent items set package that is within mlxtend. This will also allow you to control significance levels via the 'support' metric of the items purchased together rather than needing to discover this with your bespoke solution.

```
dataset = [['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'],
['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'],
['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']]


import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder

te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
df
```

[image]

http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/

```
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori

apriori(df, min_support=0.6)
```

[image]

```
apriori(df, min_support=0.6, use_colnames=True)
```

[image]